# Split text(string) in different arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, split

I'm working on a project where I receive a string variable (by calling a c# function, because my c# code makes a HTTPWebrequest and receives data back and that functions returns the correct data).

The string variable is like this:

```
Bus number:15
Bus destination: Walker Titan Road
Time: 14:39:00

Bus number:11
Bus destination: Walker Titan Road
Time: 14:42:00

Bus number:X78
Bus destination: Newcastle (city centre) Eldon Square Bus Station
Time: 14:49:00
```

Now I want to seperate these string in different arrays **in Javascript**

I want to have the following:

```
BusNumbers[]{15,11,X78}
busDestinations][{Walker Titan Road,Walker Titan Road,Newcastle (city centre) Eldon Square Bus Station}
busTimes[]{14:39:00,14:49:00,14:49:00}
```

I want this because I would like to make (in Javascript) a table where I can put each information in the right column.

I write a short program in c# to show what I want to do in javascript:

```
string[] A1 = new string[] { "15", "X86", "54" };
        string[] A2 = new string[] { "Newcastle", "City Centre", "Monument" };
        string[] A3 = new string[] { "15:05", "16:06", "16:35" };


            for (int j = 0; j < A1.Length; j++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("Busnumber: " + A1[j] + "--");
                listBox1.Items.Add(" Destination: " + A2[j] + "--");
                listBox1.Items.Add(" Time : " + A3[j] + "\n");

            }
```

(It's made with a listbox but because of the example it doesn't matter...)

But before I can make a for loop and add all the information in the table I want to know how to separate each busnumber in an array, each busDestination in an array and each busTime in an array.

Does this exist in Javascript?

Or do I need to search for another alternative?

If there is no solution I thought to make in c# 3 functions where each functions returns the correct information one functions shows all the busnumbers, one all the destinations and one all the times. Than I can call all these functions in Javascript and split the text a "," and put them all in the correct array.

Someone who can help me?
I hope that my problem is clear enough...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you modify this C# program? Maybe it would be better to make serialisation to JSON instead of parsing string to JSON in js...

Comment: @Josh Did you read it? It's C#. They're asking for a translation to Javascript

Comment: @Ian and he's suggesting another way to solve their problem that might be more straightforward.  In a comment, not an answer.  There's nothing wrong with that. Its one of the major purposes of comments, to help pull out the real question.  (Which seems in this case to be how do I get these arrays in my JS code from a String in my C# code, moreso than How do I do string processing in JS)

Comment: @ben336 I have no idea what you're talking about. All Josh said was "This is Java, not Javascript" or something like that. I was just pointing out it wasn't Java.

Comment: @Ian sorry, he deleted his comment and I thought your comment was a response to mnowotka above (since it was the only other comment at the time).  My mistake.

Comment: Not sure why you want 3 separate arrays to populate a table. If you have it in separate arrays you cannot guarantee the order in each stays the same and each element within each array has no idea to which part in the other array it belongs to. You might be better of populating a single array with objects instead. Similar to: `var data = [{ busNumber: 15, busDestination: "Walker Titan Road", time: "14:39:00" },{ busNumber: 11, busDestination: "Walker Titan Road", time: "14:42:00" }]` then you can iterate over it in a `for` loop and access each item similar to: `data[i].busNumber` and so on.

Comment: @ben336 No problem, not sure if Josh changed his comment or something (before deleting it). Just wasn't sure what you meant :)

Comment: Hi,
@mmowotka Yes I can edit the c# code...

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: ok I already have the string in a variabele in my javascript. But I dont understand what you mean with looping through the variabele ... ?

Comment: @Eclectica_: I'm referig to you building single array of objects with properties holding the information instead of 3 separate arrays to populate your table from. Separate arrays have no interconnected relationship which is fine if the data has no relation but if it should have a relation and you want to keep it you should be looking into a single array instead. It was a suggestion that's all. What ever works for you is best off course.

Comment: @Eclectica_ Hi. did any of the answers solve your issue? if so, it's good practice to tick it. This helps future visitors and is good for the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to options:

1. Write your own parser for this string using standard js string manipulation functions (substr, regex, etc). I won't provide a code here, this is something you need to do by yourself. But this is not elegant solution, this is direct solution to your problem.
2. If you can modify C# code producing this string then you may change it entirely to produce JSON instead of string. This process is called serialisation and you should get familiar with it. This solution is more elegant then the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming x matches your input (and the input is consistent with what you provided):

```
var x ='Bus number:15 \nBus destination: Walker Titan Road \nTime: 14:39:00  \nBus number:11 \nBus destination: Walker Titan Road \nTime: 14:42:00  \nBus number:X78 \nBus destination: Newcastle (city centre) Eldon Square Bus Station \nTime: 14:49:00\n';


var BusNo = x.match(/[.]*Bus number\:[\s]*([\S])+(?=\s)/g).map(function(m){return m.replace('Bus number:','');});
var BusDest = x.match(/[.]*Bus destination\:[\s]*[\w\s\(\)]*(?=\n)/g).map(function(m){return m.replace(/Bus destination\:[\s]*/,'').trim();});
var BusTime = x.match(/[.]*Time\:[\s]*[:|\d]*(?=\s)/g).map(function(m){return m.replace(/Time\:[\s]*/,'').trim();});
```

Will give what you described. n.b. there *may* be nicer regex for this.